# undefined method `bootstrap_form_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

I realize that this has been asked on here before, but I don't seem to have the same issue as the previous person as the solutions provided had no effect.

My error is a little different as well.

```
undefined method `bootstrap_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x007fd2b0c2dbe0>:0x007fd2b0c2c948>
```

The code that references the method:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@blob) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :contentType %>
  <%= f.text_field :data %>
  <%= f.text_field :form_id %>

  <%= f.submit "Create BLOB" %>
<% end %>
```

The method comes from [this gem](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms).

The gem is in the Gemfile, I have restarted the rails server a few times, and I've tried this with multiple models.

Comment: Did you install the gem into your app?  `bundle install` ?

Comment: Yes, the gem is installed

Comment: I seem to have solved this. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `bundle install` was automatically fetching version 3.0.0 of the Gem, but the GitHub lists 2.3.0 as the most recent version available.

Switching to 2.3.0 in my Gemfile fixed the issue.